# ‎No se han encontrado registros.‎ Primefaces (Datatables)

Tags: java, mysql, datatables, primefaces

Tengo un pequeño percance al ejecutar las tablas. Básicamente no me muestra los valores de la base de datos. Que están en esta imagen https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBjoS.png (Son algunos datos que se deben mostrar).

Mensaje en las tablas https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWeTV.png

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del cuerpo de la tabla, donde esta toda la estructura echa con primefaces. Por alguna razón no esta tomando los valores de la base de datos.

```
    
        <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    
    
            <ui:define name="title">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle}"></h:outputText>
            </ui:define>
    
            <ui:define name="body">
                <h:form id="UsuarioListForm">
                    <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle}">
                        <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{usuarioController.items}" var="item"
                                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{usuarioController.selected}"
                                     paginator="true"
                                     rowKey="#{item.idUsuario}"
                                     rows="10"
                                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                                     >
    
                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
    
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle_idUsuario}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.idUsuario}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle_primerNombre}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.primerNombre}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle_segundoNombre}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.segundoNombre}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle_primerapellido}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.primerapellido}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListUsuarioTitle_segundoapellido}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                
    
    </html>
```

En el controlador:

```
@Named("usuarioController")
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioController implements Serializable {

  private List<Usuario> items = null;

  public List<Usuario> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getFacade().findAll();
    }
    return items;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Pues es mensaje es bastante explicativo, que el valor que se usa para mostrar la tabla (*#{usuarioController.items}*) o es *null* o una colección o iterable vacío. ¿Cómo estás cargando ese valor? Falta el código del controlador.

Comment: Ah, entiendo. El codigo del controlador no puede subirlo por que era extenso y si esta bien te lo puedo pasar como respuesta.

Comment: Editada la pregunta, por favor borra la respuesta. El código mostrado parece correcto, tendrías que comprobar (p.ej. mostrando en el log) qué te devuelve *getFacade.findAll()*. O, alternativamente, devolver un valor a piñón fijo (crear en *getItems()* una lista con un *Usuario* definido "en código") para asegurarte de que así sí que se muestra.